# Native query where parameter LIKE - no result

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have working SQL query in Workbench:

```
SELECT tmi.* FROM tree_menu_item tmi WHERE (tmi.altname='FC' OR tmi.title='FC') AND 
(tmi.parent_title LIKE '%FC_parent%' OR 
tmi.parent_title LIKE concat(IFNULL((select parent_title from tree_menu_item where altname='FC_parent'),'xxx'),'%'))
```

But can't make it work in JpaRepository:

```java
public interface TreeMenuItemRepository extends JpaRepository<TreeMenuItem, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT tmi.* FROM tree_menu_item tmi WHERE (tmi.altname=:title OR tmi.title=:title) AND (tmi.parent_title LIKE %:parent% "
        + "OR tmi.parent_title LIKE concat(IFNULL((SELECT parent_title FROM tree_menu_item WHERE altname=:parent),'xxx'),'%'))", nativeQuery = true)
    TreeMenuItem findOneByParentTitle(@Param("parent") String parent, @Param("title") String title);
}
```

When I have turned on query logging in MySql, I can see that LIKE condition is without `%` wrapping. The workaround is to duplicate `:parent` parameter so it is not shared in LIKE condition with equal condition:

```java
public interface TreeMenuItemRepository extends JpaRepository<TreeMenuItem, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT tmi.* FROM tree_menu_item tmi WHERE (tmi.altname=:title OR tmi.title=:title) AND (tmi.parent_title LIKE %:parentLike% "
        + "OR tmi.parent_title LIKE concat(IFNULL((SELECT parent_title FROM tree_menu_item WHERE altname=:parentAlt),'xxx'),'%'))", nativeQuery = true)
  TreeMenuItem findOneByParentTitle(@Param("parentLike") String parentLike, @Param("parentAlt") String parentAlt, @Param("title") String title);
}
```

Is this bug or feature? Is there some other solution? This happens on SpringBoot v2.0.2

Comment: I'm no expert on Spring, but can you really do `tmi.parent_title LIKE %:parentLike%` ? Shouldn't you do something like `tmi.parent_title LIKE '%' || :parentLike || '%'`

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, this does the trick too. But according to [spring-data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_using_advanced_code_like_code_expressions) documentation the `%:parent` syntax is supported too.

Comment: I have now debugged the query and spring-data is storing whether the parameter is of containing type. It seems that 'equal' usage of parameter is overriding this.